# The data source properties to improve the application response time?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-was

A performance test team was testing the capacity of concurrent users of a web application
deployed on a multi-processor server. While testing 250 concurrent users, the administrator
discovers connections to the database are failing.
In response, a system administrator increased the connection pool to the maximum limit which the
database allows and increased the prepared statement cache size. The test passed, but the
application response time was slower.
How should the system administrator tune the data source properties to improve the application
response time?

A.
Change connection pools purge policy.

B.
Decrease connection pool reap time.

C.
Decrease number of free pool partitions.

D.
Decrease the prepared statement cache size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Number of shared partitions**

Specifies the number of partitions that are created in each of the shared pools.

Partition support is always enabled. The default values of 0 should be used to enable the connection pool to pick the best values for performance. In some cases where large multiprocessor systems are used, adjusting the partition support properties might help performance.

So decreasing the number of free pool partitions should do.